# Pointers and double pointers exercise

Tags: c, pointers, double-pointer

```
#include <stdio.h>

 int a;

 int main ()
 {
     int a, b;
     int *p;
     b = 8;
     p = &b;
     a = 32 + b;
     p = &a;
     *p = 32 - b;
     funct (a, &p);
     *p = 2;
     printf ("a=%d b=%d", a, b);
 }

 funct (int x, int **y)
 {
     a = 15;
     **y = x - a;
     *y = &a;
 }
```

Can someone tell me why a is equal to 9? I tried to solve it but i can't understand it really well

I tried the code in `code::blocks` and apparently `a` goes from 40 to 24 after

```
`*p=32-b`
```

Also,`p=&b` means that the pointer points to the address of b,then after `a=32+8` 
`p=&a` and the double pointer `*p= 32-b` so `*p=24` . Is `24` the address in which the pointer `p` is stored? because now the value of `a` should be 24 according to the exercise and I can't understand why.

Can someone tell me step by step how do I deal with those kind of exercise ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By the time `func` is called, `a`=24, and `p` is the address of `a`.

Inside of `function`, however, `a` refers to the *global* `a`, not the one declared in `main`.  `func` first assigns *that* `a` to be 15.  Then:

- `**y` is the `a` in `main`
- `x - a` is `main`'s `a` (24) minus the global `a` (15), yielding 9
- so `**y = x - a` sets `main`'s `a` to 9

Comment: Thank you for answering, but i can't understand why *p=32-8 implies a=24.
i mean what does *p=24 mean? is 24 an address?

Comment: `p` is a pointer to the `a` in `main` (`p = &a`); `*p = 24` means `assign 24 to the variable pointed to by p`.

Comment: @Giorgio: If `p == &a`, then `*p == a`, so `*p = 24` is the same as writing `a = 24`.

Answer (score 0):

Before this call

```
funct (a, &p);
```

the variable `a` is equal to 24 due to this statement

```
*p = 32 - b;
```

where `b` is equal to 8.

Inside the function in this statements

```
 a = 15;
 **y = x - a;
```

`a` is set to `24 - 15`  that is equal to `8` because the dereferenced pointer `*y` points to the original variable `a`.

Comment: How can `a` be 24 and 15 at the same time?

Comment: @ScottHunter  Hi the 3/4 developer.:) It is not at the same time. Before the function call a is equal to 24. And   inside the function due to the statement  **y = x - a; that is equivalent to 24 - 15 a is set to 9.

Comment: *which* `a` is set to 9?

Comment: @ScottHunter In the function.